# How to change the increment in a loop to more than one?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, count

For one of my programming projects, I was told to make one of these charts:

```
1 - 10  | *****
11 - 20 | **
21 - 30 | *******************
31 - 40 |
41 - 50 | ***
51 - 60 | ********
61 - 70 | **
71 - 80 | *****
81 - 90 | *******
91 - 100| *********
```

This is an array that when the user inputs numbers in a particular range it adds a `*` for each value entered in that range. I have already created a program that creates one of these charts. My next programming project tells me to only add an `*` for every five values entered in a particular range of numbers. If less than 5 values are entered then no `*`'s will be printed. I don't know how I should approach this problem.

Here is the code for the chart:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SixFive
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] counts = new int[10];

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter integers between 1-100");

        while(scan.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            int num = scan.nextInt();
            if (num < 1 || num > 100) 
                break;
            counts[(num - 1) / 10]++;
        }

        scan.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            System.out.format("%2d -%3d ", i*10+1, i*10+10);
            for (int j = 0; j < counts[i]; j++)
                System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to divide by 5 using the divide operator `/`? Or, to do it how your question title say, increment the counter by 5 on each iteration using `+=`?

Comment: @Andreas I wasn't really sure how I would use += because then it would mean that one asterisk would be printed if it is 5 or under when replacing `j++` with `j+=` and I am not sure what to divide 5 by.

Comment: neither `i++ to i+=5` nor `j++ to j+=` works. I am not sure what else to do. Thank you for your guys help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your inner loop, replace the condition `j < counts[i]` by `j < counts[i] / 5` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.format("%2d -%3d | ", i * 10 + 1, i * 10 + 10);
    for (int j = 0; j < counts[i] / 5; j++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```